# How do I get this FRQI equation?

Tags: quantum-gate, linear-algebra, hadamard

I have been working with FRQI and there is this equation in a paper is given. Can anyone explain how they get that just by multiplying by $\mathcal{H}$ ?
$$\mathcal{H}\left(|0\rangle^{\otimes2n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2^n}|0\rangle\otimes\sum_{i=0}^{2^{2n}-1}|i\rangle$$

Comment: Please try to use [Mathjax](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation) to display equations and not images. Also please include all information necessary to answer your question. What is FRQI? What is $\mathcal{H}$? Perhaps you can also provide a reference to the paper if you think it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $\mathcal{H}$ is equivalent to
$$ (I\otimes H^{\otimes2n})|0\rangle^{\otimes2n+1} $$

Second, the multi-qubit hadarmard's definition: $$H^{\otimes n}|0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}} \sum_{i=0}^{2n-1}|i\rangle $$

For $H^{\otimes2n}$:
$$ H^{\otimes 2n}|0\rangle=\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i=0}^{2^{2n}-1}|i\rangle  $$

Now it easier to see:
$$ \mathcal{H}(|0\rangle^{\otimes2n+1}) = (I\otimes H^{\otimes2n})|0\rangle^{\otimes2n+1}  = \frac{1}{2^n}|0\rangle\otimes\sum_{i=0}^{2^{2n}-1}|i\rangle$$
where $|0\rangle^{\otimes 2n+1}$ is the initial state